# Rails 3 assets not compressed

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

My assets are not being compressed. I'm using `3.2.18`, with asset group having these gems :

```
group :assets do
  gem "compass-rails"
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'elementaljs-rails'
  gem 'i18n-js'
  gem 'tilt',   '~> 1.4.1'
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'turbo-sprockets-rails3'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
  gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.1.1'
  gem 'ejs'
  gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
  gem 'angular-ui-sortable-rails', github: "sherwyngoh/angular-ui-sortable-rails"
end
```

This is my assets related production config :

```
config.serve_static_assets = false
  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
  config.assets.css_compressor = :sass
  config.assets.compile = false
  config.assets.digest = true
```

When I do `RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile`, and take a look at `public/assets/application-xxx.css` I see the regular css file like I do when running server in development. Why is not getting compressed?

**Update**

I had RAILS_EVN=production in this question, that was not the cause of assets not compressing, I just typed in wrong.

Comment: Is it because you typoed RAILS_ENV?

Comment: @FrederickCheung unfortunately that wasn't the cause

Answer (score 0):

In rails 3.x you need to set

```
config.assets.compress = true
```

for assets to be compressed (see the [configuring rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.21/configuring.html#configuring-assets) guide)

Comment: thanks for the response I tried it. And now I get error on my rake task `rake aborted!
Sass::SyntaxError: Invalid CSS after ".": expected class name, was "#ff0"` but my css is not invalid works just fine